# Yesod Not in scope: type constructor or class Form error

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm just following the Yesod examples from the docs [blog example advanced](https://www.yesodweb.com/book-1.6/blog-example-advanced), but I'm getting this error when doing `stack runghc main.hs`:

```
main.hs:186:14: error:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘Form’
    Perhaps you meant one of these:
      ‘AForm’ (imported from Yesod), ‘MForm’ (imported from Yesod),
      ‘WForm’ (imported from Yesod)
    |
186 | entryForm :: Form Entry
    |              ^^^^

main.hs:237:27: error:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘Form’
    Perhaps you meant one of these:
      ‘AForm’ (imported from Yesod), ‘MForm’ (imported from Yesod),
      ‘WForm’ (imported from Yesod)
    |
237 | commentForm :: EntryId -> Form Comment
    |
```

Not sure what it really means. Is it because some difference in the Yesod versions being used? I'm using Yesod 1.6.0.6.

The full code is [here](https://pastebin.com/SNxcPqKr).

Comment: The full code you have linked gives me 404 page.

Comment: Thanks @Sibi, my account was just flagged, don't know why and SO doesn't allow to paste such a long text. Not it's been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you have commented and slightly modified the `Form` type alias declaration compared to what is in the blog. You need this line somewhere in your code in order to define what `Form` is:

```
type Form x = Html -> MForm Handler (FormResult x, Widget)
```

Then, you shall face the following type errors:

- in the definition of `postBlogR`, in line `entryId <- runDB $ insert entryForm`. The problem is that `insert` requires type `Entry` while you provide `entryForm :: Form Entry`. I guess you meant to pass `entry` there?
- Similar as before, but in `postEntryR`: I think you want `runDB $ insert comment` in place of `runDB $ insert commentForm`?
- `commentForm`: From the fact that you are not using the `entryId` argument anywhere and that it is the only thing in scope that seems to match the types, I infer that you want to replace `EntryId` with `entryId`

After these fixes the code compiles on my side with yesod 1.6.